# sqlite get sum of data by weekly

Tags: android, sqlite

I have database table that stores data daily

My table `current_list` contains:

- `id` (autoincrement)
- `day` (DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT (date('now')))
- `app_data` (INTGER)
- `mobile_data` (INTEGER)

From this table I am able to get data weekly by executing the below query

```
SELECT id AS id, strftime('%W', day) AS week, app_data, mobile_data
FROM current_list order by week;
```

which gives me

```
| id | week | app_data | mobile_data
| 01 | 00   | 100      |  200
| 02 | 00   | 200      |  300
| 03 | 00   | 400      |  670
| 04 | 01   | 700      |  340
| 05 | 01   | 600      |  560 
| 06 | 01   | 560      |  230
```

Now, I need sum of `app_data`, `mobile_data` weeklywise.
It should be like

```
| week | Sum(app_data) | Sum(mobile_data)
| 00   | 700           |  1170
| 01   | 1860          |  1300
```

Can anyone help in this?

Comment: SELECT id AS id, strftime('%W', day) AS week, app_data, mobile_data FROM current_list order by week GROUP BY strftime('%W', day)

Comment: `SELECT strftime('%W', day) AS week, sum(app_data), sum(mobile_data) FROM current_list order by week GROUP BY week`
This query is useful. But this one gives week number in year, May I know how get week number in month.

Comment: i know it's too latae but i hope this will help to other , please check [here](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)

Answer (score 4):

SELECT strftime('%W', day) AS week, sum(app_data), sum(mobile_data) FROM current_list order by week GROUP BY week

Comment: Yes this useful. But this one gives week number in year, May I know how get week number in month.